# How to write EEPROM data into USB device(pen-drive) using 32bit Atmel Avr micro controller

Tags: usb

I want to write eeprom(AT25160B) data to usb device(pendrive)using AVR32 (AT32UC3A1256-AUT)microcontroller,eeprom is interfaced with AVR32 via SPI

And in which format data is written in usb device(pendrie)? Thanks in advance

Comment: You mention both USB and PSI. Which will it be?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen on the contrary, that actually is the one part that is clear - the EEPROM is SPI and the pen drive is USB.  But overall the question lacks the required narrow specificity to fit within the mission of this site.

Comment: aryan - I have reverted back to your original question You must not completely change a question via edits, since you already have answers to your original question. If you completely change the question, then the existing answers make no sense for the *new* question! Also, you have already asked your new question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/429295/configuration-of-usb-in-at32uc3a1256). Therefore, you are not allowed to create a duplicate question, by repeating the same new question here. I suggest you read the [tour] and [help] to learn more about this site. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> How to write EEPROM data into USB device(pen-drive) using 32bit Atmel
>   Avr micro controller

If you need to write data to a generic USB pen drive, your MCU must implement ***USB host protocol*** as a start. It doesn't matter where the data came from, EEPROM or else. Luckily, the [AT32UC3A1256](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/doc32058.pdf) MCU family does include a version of USB host controller, part of so-called "OTG mode", see Section 30 of the datasheet.

To start the OTG in host mode, your MCU must implement ID detection circuitry, enable VBUS power at the connector, and then arrange for detection of connect event.

Once the connection detected, your code must issue "port reset", and start sending SOF ( Start Of Frame) packets. And then issue a set of standard control transactions ( "GET_DESCRIPTOR", then "SET_ADDRESS", and then "SET_INTERFACE" and SET_CONFIGURATION), which constitutes "enumeration". Without this basic enumeration protocol the USB flash drive will not operate.

As embedded host, your implementation can support a limited set of USB devices. In this particular case you can implement drivers for only one class of devices - Mass Storage Class. To make it work, your code should analyze the descriptor information returned by flash drive during enumeration process, and then perform all necessary formal inquiries (like device capabilities, get its format info, etc.) before you be able to write files. 
To initiate host transaction, you just need to program 256 32-bit registers correctly, but Microchp/ATmel does have code examples on [how to operate their controller in host mode](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/Atmel-42344-USB-Host-Interface-UHI-for-Mass-Storage-Class-MSC_ApplicationNote_AT09339.pdf), even with particular support for MSC devices.

Obviously if you want to be able to retrieve your data, you need to follow known data formats like FAT16, FAT32, NTFS, etc.

The EEPROM interface to AVR using SPI is a more trivial part of your endeavor. This is how do you do the process in question.